# Need efficiency hack for debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, customization, toolbar

I frequently use `Debug -> Exceptions -> check CLR Exceptions` during debugging sessions.  Sometimes, an exception gets thrown and handled, but I really want to find the source of the exception.  In order to do this without seeing first-chance exceptions that I don't care about, I start my app, and then check CLR Exceptions:

[image]

This gets really tedious, and I'd love to have a toggle button in my VS2010 toolbar that allows me to only set/reset CLR Exceptions at will, without having to key in <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, check the box, and then click OK (and then do the same process again to turn off the exceptions).  I went into the toolbar customization, but all I could get was a button that bring up the Exceptions dialog.  This is obviously less efficient than hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>.

Does anyone know of another way to add this?  Will it require a VS addin?  A keystroke mapping would be nice as well.

I've never used the Macro Recorder in VS ever, but maybe this is one place where it's necessary?

Comment: Regarding your PS.
Short answer is: <kbd>Any</kbd>
Long answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70356/key-stroke-combination-markdown

Comment: I edited your question to use the <kbd> tag, as an excuse for myself to use it :)  Also, check this for some fun with <kbd> : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974

Comment: @Cristi thanks!  hopefully, I won't forget that tag the next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Use the macro recorder to record the steps.

Rename the macro to something mnemonic.

go to (tools)(customize)

at the bottom there is a keyboard button you can use to map that macro to a key or

the commands tab will allow you to (add command) to any specific menu or tool bar.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  That macro recorder gets on my nerves because I bring it up by accident all of the time, and then I can't figure out why my IDE isn't doing anything.  :)

Comment: I was looking for the same productivity hack as OP (for VS 2008, but shouldn't matter...). I tried the macro recorder, but all it does is bring up the 'Exceptions' dialog. This is the complete source of the recorded macro:

Sub StopOnFirstChanceExceptions()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Exceptions")
End Sub